# How to extract part of an aeson value that satisfies a condition?

Tags: json, haskell, filter, haskell-lens, aeson

I have a JSON structure which looks like this:

```
{
  "instances": [
    {
      "instanceId": "i-1234",
      "tags": [
        {
          "value": "author1useast1",
          "key": "hostname"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "instanceId": "i-5678",
      "tags": [
        {
          "value": "proxy1useast1",
          "key": "hostname"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get a list of all `instances/instanceId` where `instances/tags` has a `hostname` of `author1useast1`.

I have thought about getting a list of instances with `key "instances" . _Values` first, then mapping it into a list of (`instanceId`, `tags`) tuples and then doing the filtering. However that looks very inefficient to me.

Is there a more elegant / idiomatic way of doing this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The idiomatic way is to parse the entire JSON document, then write a filter function for the ADT which results from that.

Comment: Yes, so I already have the above JSON as a `Value`, and I know how to filter e.g. the `instanceId`s out of it. However, my condition involves a different part of the tree, i.e. the `tags`, and I would like to know how to filter instanceIds where the tags match the condition.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear - parse the document to an ADT which models the specific structure of your document (e.g. `data Tag = Tag { value :: Text, key :: Text }; data Instance = Instance { ID :: Text, tag :: Tag }; newtype Instances = Instances [Instance]`). What if the JSON is well-formed, but doesn't match your desired structure? Say, there is an object with `instanceId` and `tags` nested inside one of the tags field of some other object. Any filtering of `Value` will not detect this; but if you parse to your own ADT first, the structure of your document will be enforced.

Comment: Ah, I misinterpreted "ADT" as "AST", sorry :-) But I think freestyles's answer below is quite exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use lens, you can use `filtered` optic, as instance:

```
  key "instances" . values
. filtered (anyOf (key "tags" . values) $
    allOf (key "key") (=="hostname")
    <&&> allOf (key "value") (=="author1useast1"))
. key "instanceId"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: A small addendum:

I asked hayoo for <&&> and found it in the "cond" and "control-bool" packages, both of which weren't available in stack lts-7.3 that I'm using. The solution was to just define it myself as `liftM2 (&&)`. Now it works like a charm!

Comment: `<&&> = liftA2 (&&)` will be more general.